# vue-router not updating component outside of router-view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have my root Vue component setup like this:

```
<div>
    <main-nav></main-nav>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

So, main-nav is a component outside of the router-view. I'm having trouble with the main-nav updating itself properly when data changes or when navigating from route to route. Here's a simplified version of main-nav:

```
<template>
  <li v-show="loggedIn">
    <a @click="logout">Logout</a>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
  import { isLoggedIn, logout } from '@/tools/Auth'

  export default {
    computed: {
      loggedIn: {
        cache: false,
        get() {
          return isLoggedIn()
        }
      }
    },

    methods: {
      logout() {
        logout().then(() => {
          this.$router.push({ name: 'Login' })
          // this is necessary or the nav isn't updated after logout
          this.$forceUpdate()
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

First I had to set `cache: false` on the `loggedIn` property or it wouldn't update at all after logging out. I also had to add a `$forceUpdate()` after logout in order for the component to refresh itself. Now I'm having the same problem after login - the component just doesn't refresh. I can see in the vue dev tools that `loggedIn` is `true`, but it won't show the logout link until I refresh the page.

It's not a race condition, there's nothing async going on at the moment. I'm just setting and deleting a cookie right now to get this working.

Anyone have an idea why I'm having these issues? I'm fairly familiar with vue-router from other projects and I've read the documentation but maybe I missed something?

Comment: What is that imported `isLoggedIn`? Is it observable? How does value changes of `isLoggedIn()` is notified? Can you show its implementation?

Comment: `isLoggedIn` is just a wrapper for `Vue.Cookie.get('auth-token')`. The cookie is set when you login, then I redirect with vue-router. You can see that the cookie is set and vue dev tools shows me that `loggedIn` is `true` for the main-nav component. But the dom doesn't update.

Comment: I suspect cookie operation is not observable, devtools might be just re-querying the entire Vue model, but actually Vue might not have triggered a property change notification for bindings to update. This is a good use case to use events instead of computed property IMHO.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help, if you find a solution, hope you can self answer your question so that it might help [someone else in the future](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: You are right, it's even mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) that computed properties are never refreshed if there are no reactive dependencies. The solution seems to be to use a method or as you suggested, events. A third solution comes to mind as well: I should probably write the "loggedIn" state to the store, that way it would be reactive, then persist it via a vuex plugin that writes that state to a cookie. Feel free to add an answer so I can mark it as such!